# show UIPageviewcontroller childcontrollers based on array count

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to display childcontrollers in the UIPageviewController class based on the array count which i get from the API response . for eg. one child controller can have one imageview and label below it  and so multiple childcontrollers can have differnt content.

Answer (score 0):

In my code, create an array of view controllers (could also be dynamic) for:

```
self.introPages = [self introContentViewControllers];
```

Like this:

```
- (NSArray *)introContentViewControllers {
  return @[
           [[IntroContentViewController alloc] 
             initWithIndex:0
             text:NSLocalizedString(@"Intro.Page1.title", nil)
             image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"onboarding-10-party"]],
  // Etc.
}
```

That should do what you are requesting.